# How to Convert hexadecimal integer into a string in c++ (for html colors)?

Tags: html, c++, string, colors, int

Bonjourno, Bonsoir, Konbanwa, Ave [...]

I try to convert int in hexadecimal and then into string to generate html color...

Do you know a way to do it?

I have try:

```
        int rouge=  0x0 ;    //red in french
        int vert=   0x0 ;    //green
        int bleu=   0xff;    //blue
        int couleur=0x0 ;    //color

        bleu*=256*256;
        vert*=256;

        couleur=rouge+vert+bleu; 

        cout<<"couleur"<<couleur<<endl;

        stringstream ss2;    // #include <sstream> if someone want to do it also ^^
        ss2 <<hex<<couleur; // convert  int to stringstream  works if decimal
        cout<<ss2<<hex<<endl;

        string string_couleur = ss2.str();  // convert streamstring to string

        for (int nombre_0_devant=6-string_couleur.size(); nombre_0_devant>0;nombre_0_devant--) string_couleur="0"+string_couleur;  // just a line to add needed 0   ff --> 0000ff

        html+="#"+string_couleur+">";
```

It gives:

```
0x28f738
```

:(

thank you for reading!

Comment: What part of the code "gives" 0x28f738? Is that the value of `html` at the end? Also, what would you want it to give?

Comment: It was cout<<ss2<<hex<<endl;   sorry I found that I didn't printed at the right place :s   Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry

```
cout<<"string"<<string_couleur<<"\n";
```

Works!

I have not print the good variable.

I do not delete the question because maybe it can help someone.